# Custom button to input a character into a TextBox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I just recently started learning Windows Phone 7 development, C# and Silverlight. I'm making a Morse Code Translator as an exercise but I ran into a problem. I made three buttons for the user to input morse code into a `TextBox`. One is for period, the second is for line and the last one is for space. The problem is that I can't seem to input more than one character into the `TextBox` using this method and they simply overwrite each other.

Here's how I tried to do it in the click event.

```
private void bShort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    char dot = ".";   
    TBoxMorse2.Text = dot.ToString();
}
```

How should I go fixing this problem?

Sorry if this has been asked. I tried to search for it but didn't find any similar problems here on StackOverflow.

Thank you all in advance for checking this out!

Comment: Why not: TBoxMorse2.Text += dot.ToString(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're explicitly overwriting the value:

```
TBoxMorse2.Text = dot.ToString();
```

By setting the property, you overwrite anything that's already in there.  You don't want to set the property to the new value.  You want to set it to the existing value *plus* the new value:

```
TBoxMorse2.Text += dot.ToString();
// or more explicitly, if you're not familiar with the += operator...
TBoxMorse2.Text = TBoxMorse2.Text + dot.ToString();
// or if you want to use string.Format,
// since I once heard somewhere that it performs better than concatenation...
TBoxMorse2.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", TBoxMorse2.Text, dot.ToString());
```

As usual, there are multiple ways to do it.

Side note, your `TBoxMorse2` variable name isn't considered idiomatic C#.  (As implied by the syntax highlighter on StackOverflow incorrectly highlighting it as a Type instead of a Variable.)  C# convention prefers that variable names don't begin with a capital letter.  Something like this:

```
tBoxMorse2
// or...
_TBoxMorse2
```

Comment: I think the third option wouldn't matter in this case, as concatenation of short strings is a very common operation and the compiler would rewrite it if any savings could be had.

Comment: @Will: Agreed.  It's generally just habit for me, but I figured it couldn't hurt to include it as another example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pickup the the text available in the text box and concatinate the new character to the text.

```
TextBox2.text=TextBox2.text + dot.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

`char dot = "."` is incorrect that's how you declare/assing a string
`char dot = '.'` or char dot = char(\u the unicode value of a dot

Comment: I didn't. That's weird. I probably pushed the arrow by accident. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: well it's ok.. it's still at -1 no biggy